# How to pass php array string to javascript function as a parameter?

Tags: javascript, php

I am iterating through a php array to display a list of photo filters.
I need to be able to pass the selected filter name to my javascript function to load it, for now I am only able to get the `$i` id but the full filter name would be so much more easier.

How can pass `$filters[$i]` to `getFilterName()`?

```
<?php
    for ($i = 0; $filters[$i]; $i++)
    {
        if (strpos($filters[$i], '.png'))
        {
            ?>
            <!-- get php variable for javascript : -->
            <div id="filter-target" style="display: none;">
                <?php
                    echo htmlspecialchars($i);
                ?>
            </div>
            <!-- ... -->

            <?php
            echo '<div tabindex="-1" class="filter_box" onclick="getFilterName('.$i.')">';
                echo '<img class="filter" src="pictures/filters/'.$filters[$i].'"/>';
            echo '</div>';
        }
    }
?>
```

Thank you!

Comment: So on click event, you are unable to pass name of image is it?

Comment: @quickSwap absolutely

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the filename is a string, you need to escape it in `' '` like so:

```
<?php
    for ($i = 0; $filters[$i]; $i++)
    {
        if (strpos($filters[$i], '.png'))
        {
            ?>
            <!-- get php variable for javascript : -->
            <div id="filter-target" style="display: none;">
                <?php
                    echo htmlspecialchars($i);
                ?>
            </div>
            <!-- ... -->

            <?php
            echo '<div tabindex="-1" class="filter_box" onclick="getFilterName(\''.$filters[$i].'\')">';
                echo '<img class="filter" src="pictures/filters/'.$filters[$i].'"/>';
            echo '</div>';
        }
    }
?>
```

Otherwise it would treat the string as a variable name in JavaScript and wouldnt fint it because it doesnt exist.

Comment: Amazing! Thank you so much Maurice

Comment: No problem @Martin. Glad I could help out. Feel free to accept my answer if it helped.